# Uploading 200 pdf into MC and needing the link in a data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, pdf

I need to upload over 200 pdfs into MC every quarter. After that I need each pdf link to be inserted into a data extension. I've been doing this by hand but is there any way to get the link into the data extension faster? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The REST API for Content Builder Assets is one of the most mature web services in the platform.

I'd suggest starting with a [simple Asset query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/references/mc_rest_assets/assetSimpleQuery.html) in Postman like this, which will return pages of PDF assets:

`https://{{et_subdomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/asset/v1/content/assets?$page=1&$pagesize=10&$orderBy=name asc&$filter=assetType.name=pdf&$fields=id,customerKey,fileProperties`

Salesforce provides a Postman collection that includes examples.  You can find that [here](https://www.postman.com/salesforce-developers/workspace/salesforce-developers/collection/14448118-2835a976-010c-4548-92f8-f42c0382758e).